# BlocBuilder not necessary

Tags: flutter, navigation, bloc, flutter-cubit

I am continuing a Flutter project of mine after quite some time and I no longer understand why a very basic pattern works.

As far as I remember and what I understand from the documentation, I need a `BlocBuilder` to update a screen upon a state change. However, my app also updates the screen without a `BlocBuilder` upon calling a `Cubit` function. So when I click on a navigation tab, the other page in the stack appears on front.

Why is this, even though I am only working with `StateLessWidget`s and no `BlocBuilder`?

```dart
class HomePageClient extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePageClient({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocProvider<HomeCubitClient>(
     create: (_) => HomeCubitClient(),
     child: HomeViewClient(nextJobsBloc: nextJobsBloc,
        specialTasksBloc: specialTasksBloc),);
  }
}

class HomeViewClient extends StatelessWidget {
  String? clientId;
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final selectedTab = context.select((HomeCubitClient cubit) => cubit.state.tab);
    clientId = context.select((AppBloc bloc) => bloc.state.client!.clientId);
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: selectedTab.index,
        children: [
          HomeMainClient(),
          PropertyListPage(clientId: clientId),
        ],

      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            _HomeTabButton(
              groupValue: selectedTab,
              value: HomeTabClient.home,
              label: 'HOME',
            ),
            _HomeTabButton(
              groupValue: selectedTab,
              value: HomeTabClient.properties,
              label: 'PROPERTIES',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _HomeTabButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const _HomeTabButton({
    required this.groupValue,
    required this.value,
    required this.label,
  });

  final HomeTabClient groupValue;
  final HomeTabClient value;
  final String label;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          foregroundColor: groupValue != value
              ? Colors.black
              : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          ),
      onPressed: () => context.read<HomeCubitClient>().setTab(value),
      child: Text(label),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlocBuilder we know its purpose is to rebuild the widget when the state changes.

After the Release of Bloc version 6.1.0. We got the access for three different methods.

```
context.read<T>()
context.watch<T>()
context.select<T>()
```

Now obviously you can rebuild a widget using `BlocConsumer,BlocBuilder`
but let's say you need to subscribe to many blocs so there came a need for more granular approach like used in your bloc.

Simply In your case:

```
final selectedTab = context.select((HomeCubitClient cubit) => cubit.state.tab);
```

Is the one responsible for the rebuild of the widget.

`context.select` here basically looks for the HomeCubitClient and subscribes to its state. It **rebuilds only** when the tab variable is changed. The line bellow it subscribes to another bloc and your widget will rebuild when `clientId` varies inside new state.

you can achieve similar thing using `BlocBuilder` and its `buildWhen` method by nesting two of them which is tedious.

Answer (score 2):

```
final selectedTab = context.select((HomeCubitClient cubit) => cubit.state.tab);
```

In this line in build method of `HomeViewClient` you are listening for `HomeCubitClient` state updates. So if `HomeCubitClient` is changed then you active tab is changing correspondingly

If you check the code of `BlocBuilder` and its parent `BlocBuilderBase` you will see that it's doing literally the same thing (but also overrides `didUpdateWidget` and `didChangeDependencies`). So it's recommended to use `BlocBuilder` in your case